# Lazy load module outside src Angular CLI

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I'm working in a larger project where we need to store modules outside an application. Anyone know if it's possible to lazy load a module that's stored outside the src folder?

Example:

```
./
 - src/
   - app/
     - app.router.ts
       ...
 - +lazy/
   - lazy.module.ts
   - lazy.component.ts
   - lazy.router.ts
```

In app.router.ts:

```
{
  path: '',
  loadChildren: '../+lazy/lazy.module#LazyModule'
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, keep in mind that the lazy loaded module need to have a default export.

```
export default class LazyModule { }
```

Router:

```
{
    path: '',
    loadChildren: () =>
        System.import('../+lazy/lazy.module').then((m: any) => {
            return m.default;
        })
}
```

Comment: What is System Here, I am getting error saying System is not defined.
Do you mean System is SystemJS, If it is SystemJS how do I import it in my route.
Is there a way I can make module path as dynamic. I will be getting that dynamic module path from an API.